# Under AWS boto3 route53 api for python: update_health_check failed with parameter 'Disabled' not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-route53

I ran into this issue today when I try to create a aws lambda function that can disable the route53 healthcheck once a failover happpened.

The function basically wait for a failover alarm in route53 and execute `update_health_check(HealthCheckId=healthcheck_id, Disabled=True)` The API was found under route53 AWS boto3 module from
[route53 API for boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.update_health_check). As you can see, the paramter "Disabled" is clearly defined within the document.

The function worked perfectly locally. I am also running boto3==1.9.66 locally.

However when I upload my lambda function to AWS. I ran into below issues. Looks like the "Disabled" parameter is somehow not defined in boto3 in AWS itself?

```
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 621, in _convert_to_request_dict
api_params, operation_model)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "Disabled", must be one of: HealthCheckId, HealthCheckVersion, IPAddress, Port, ResourcePath, FullyQualifiedDomainName, SearchString, FailureThreshold, Inverted, HealthThreshold, ChildHealthChecks, EnableSNI, Regions, AlarmIdentifier, InsufficientDataHealthStatus, ResetElements
```

One work around i can think of is to upload my local boto3 module to AWS as well. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to bundle boto3 with your code or wait for the [Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) to be updated.

Bundling boto3 and botocore with your code is a [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html):

> Control the dependencies in your function's deployment package. The
>   AWS Lambda execution environment contains a number of libraries such
>   as the AWS SDK for the Node.js and Python runtimes (a full list can be
>   found here: Lambda Execution Environment and Available Libraries). To
>   enable the latest set of features and security updates, Lambda will
>   periodically update these libraries. These updates may introduce
>   subtle changes to the behavior of your Lambda function. **To have full
>   control of the dependencies your function uses, we recommend packaging
>   all your dependencies with your deployment package.**

If you use [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for your boto3 dependency, you could update multiple functions easily by updating the layer once you've tested with a new version of boto3.

There is an [in-depth blog post](https://www.serverlessops.io/blog/aws-lambda-and-python-boto3-bundling) on the topic of bundling boto3 from Tom McLaughlin.